# Git Bash doesn't display characters correctly, using Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, visual-studio-code, unicode, git-bash

I use Git Bash as the default terminal profile on Windows. When I execute this command, I get the below output:

```bash
memlab run --scenario tests/oversized-object/index.js

> 'command' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ��� \
�������ļ�
```

The VS Code `terminal.integrated`  font family is `Consolas`.
How to get the characters to display correctly?

**UPDATE:**

When I run the command by using Git Bash(not VSCode integrated), the output I copied and pasted to this post:

```bash
> memlab run --scenario examples/01-get-started/index.js

'command' �����ڲ����ⲿ���Ҳ���ǿ����еĳ���
�������ļ�
Scenario file doesn't exist: null
Use `memlab help` or `memlab <COMMAND> -h` to get helper text
```

I don't know why there are those characters.

But the actual output is:

[image]

Comment: What are these characters supposed to be? Share some example Unicode code points. Does the font you picked for integrated terminal support these codepoints? Also, check lots of material on this matter on the internet, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75948734/7264739`

Comment: @Destroy666 Thanks for your reply. I updated my post. I also tried the solution you provided, but it does not solve the issue. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions about characters and font. Either copy the exact text that should be output or check the code points.

Comment: @Destroy666 The font family of integrated terminal is `Consolas`, how can I check the code points?

Comment: Paste the real character that needs to be printed into Google and Unicode websites will tell you. Or like I said, paste the real unchanged text here.